# What are these wire connectors and where can I get replacements?

Tags: electrical, wiring, vacuum

The closest name I found from searching online is "crimp terminals", specifically the first I believe would be "female round crimp terminal" and the second "female right angle crimp terminal", however I am not sure if that is descriptive enough to ensure I can find and order the proper replacements.

These are from a Dyson vacuum if it helps. The wire itself is severed, so I was planning to purchase same gauge wire (AWG22) and the 2 terminals.

[image: Connector 1 Image 1]

[image: Connector 1 Image 2]

[image: Connector 2]

Comment: I have never seen the first one.  For the second  search for  "right angle female spade terminal" There are different sizes so you may go to an auto parts store and get a few  to see what size you have. You could also check with Dyson for the part numbers.

Comment: I think the top ones are female Winchester but the wrong crimping tool was used. The bottom is a 1/4” female spade or disconnect with a 90 these are more common and this one was properly crimped on the conductor and insulator.

Comment: The top ones can be purchased at any appliance repair shop. Those connectors are commonly used in  electric skillets, Crockpots, electric grills, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first (2) photo's show a Female "Bullet" crimp connector. The third shows a Female "Spade" connector. Both are available on Amazon.

They are sized according to wire gauge; that is the color coded crimp connector's only accommodate certain wire diameter's.

You may want to consider that a new bullet connector may not fit securely enough to stay in place. You may want to consider soldering the wire at the break and wrapping it with shrink tube. I've made repairs similar to your's and had to reduce the opening of the new bullet to keep it secure.

Comment: some are colour coded, these ones aren't

Comment: I ended up buying the whole "assembly", the part name is "Dyson DC43 and DC66 Yoke Loom".